# Publication Target won't delete because it's in use in Web 8

Tags: cme, web8

We upgraded from 2013 SP1 to Web 8. We are now using new Business Process Type for publishing and want to delete our old Publication Targets.

We are unable to delete a Publication Target which was used in a Mailing even after successfully decommissioning it.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Web 8, but have you pointed it at a new deployer and unpublished?

Comment: You can set the publication target false on the tridion content manger config file.